# Debugging 403's?

Tags: iis, logging, http-status-code-403

whats the best way to investigate why a server is returning a 403 for a http web request?

Can an iis server be configured to provide a more detailed **internal** log for 403's?

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to start is to analyze returned headers (using `curl -vvv`, or inspecting the request using your favorite web browser development tool).